# Typescript: Use a class with Mixins as a type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use Typescript Mixins to compose my class instead of duplicating behaviors (like the getImage function below).

I followed those instructions https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html and it worked well.

But there's a problem I can't solve is that now I can't use my classes with mixins as a type anymore (see the functions at the end).

Do you know how I could get around this?

Thanks

```
// A - Some Mixins

type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

function withStoredImages(Base: Constructor) {
  return class extends Base {
    storageToken?: string;

    getImage(formatSlug: string) {
      if (!this.storageToken) return null;
      return `${formatSlug}${this.storageToken}.png`;
    }
  };
}

// B - The actual class I want to create

class BaseEntity {
  name: string;

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

export const Entity = withStoredImages(BaseEntity);

const myEntity = new Entity('1', 'Bobby');

// Works
console.log(myEntity.storageToken);

// Works
console.log(myEntity.getImage('original'));

// Good. We can use BaseEntity as a type for our arg
export function printBaseEntity(entity: BaseEntity) {
  // Works
  console.log(entity.name);

  // Error: "Property 'storageToken' does not exist on type 'BaseEntity'."
  // Makes sense, since it's before we apply the withStoredImages mixin
  console.log(entity.storageToken);
}

// Error: "'Entity' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Entity'?"
// Why can't I use "Entity" as a type for my arg? Let's try using "typeof Entity" then...
export function printEntity(entity: Entity) {
  console.log(entity.name);
}

export function printEntity2(entity: typeof Entity) {
  // ... Error: "Property 'storageToken' does not exist on type 'typeof (Anonymous class)'?"
  console.log(entity.storageToken);
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rbk3fn?file=entity.model.ts

Comment: SOme time ago I have written an article about typing mixins in typescript. Toy can find it on [medium](https://captain-yossarian.medium.com/typescript-object-oriented-typings-4fd42ce14c75) or my [blog](https://catchts.com/oop-style#typed_inheritance)

Comment: Thanks. I've seen that other method in the docs but I can't use since some of my mixins need some data to initialize. In the above I can do `export const Entity = withStoredImages(BaseEntity, otherParam);`. This can't be done with your method since you're using this syntax `class MyClass extends Mixin(Foo, Bar, Baz) { }`

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Error: "'Entity' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Entity'?"
export function printEntity(entity: Entity) {
  console.log(entity.name);
}
```

Above error makes sense because `Entity` is not a literal class, it refers to const.

Consider this simplified example:

```js
const foo = class { }

type Foo = foo // error
```

You are allowed to use class in a type scope only if it was declared as a class declaration and not expression.

In this case you should use `typeof Entity`. However. `typeof Entity` represents type of constructor. It means that you are not allowed to use `storageToken` property, because `typeof Entity` is a constructor function. You should call it with `new`. Consider this example:

```js
export function printEntity2(entity: typeof Entity) {
  const x = new entity()
  x.getImage('hello') // ok
  x.storageToken // ok
  console.log(x.storageToken); // ok
}
```

Now it works as expected

Comment: You're creating a new instance everytime the function is called?? I don't understand. The function is taking an entity (of the class Entity) in argument not a class. Why do you call new entity()? The arg entity holds the instance of Entity... Still, thanks for your answer

Comment: There is s huge difference between `typeof Entity` and `Entity`. Firrst is a class constructor, second is a class instance type. It depends on what you want to achieve. What do you want to pass to the function ?

Comment: I want to pass an instance of the Entity class. Something like `printEntityName(e: Entity) { console.log(e.name); }`. And if I try to pass something else than an entity it should throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

One way, though clumsy, is to declare a new type this way

```
type EntityType = BaseEntity & { storageToken?: string; getImage(formatSlug: string): unknown; };
```

This type now can be used as parameter of methods `printEntity` and `printEntity2`.

```
 function printEntity(entity: EntityType) {
   console.log(entity.name);
 }

  function printEntity2(entity: EntityType) {
   console.log(entity.storageToken);
 }
```

However `EntityType` is not callable, so you can't call `new EntityType(...)`. You still need to create instances with the `Entity` constructor: `const myEntity = new Entity('1', 'Bobby') as EntityType;`.

So, an incomplete / clumsy solution... I wonder if both types could be combined together in an elegant way.

Comment: Thanks but this is way too verbose. I can have several mixins and the idea was to have a cleaner code. This is not cleaner sadly.